# Attempting to use JQuery to change an img src of draggable object when dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Basically, I have .dragme (object being dragged), .dropzone1 (place to be dropped at) and an image I want .dragme to become once it has been dropped.

So far I have this

```
$(".dropzone1").droppable({
    accept:".dragme",
    drop: function() {
        alert("DROPPED");
    }
});
```

So, that code works, once .dragme has been dropped in place I get the alert. But I've tried using .attr to change the image source of .dragme in place of where the alert is currently (the alert also works if I put it into the below code, but the image still doesn't change):

```
$(".dropzone1").droppable({
    accept:".dragme",
    drop: function() {
        $(".dragme").attr("src", "../imgs/newimage.png");
    }
});
```

I've looked through other answers to similar questions, but none of the solutions worked, any help is greatly appreciated.

This is a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QsjqP/127/) but i can't get my images onto it, they're only 30x30 png's anyway. I made it so that the alert is working so if anyone can have a play and get it so that the red block changes colour or into an image when it lands on the blue, that'd be great!

Comment: Would you be kind and create some jsFiddle?

Comment: try `prop()` and maybe the url is not correct?!

Comment: proper doesn't work either, and the url is okay, I'm using komodo edit so it tells me if the image link isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QsjqP/123/)**

```
    $(".dragme").draggable();

$(".dropzone1").droppable({
    accept:".dragme",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      $(".dragme").attr("src", "../imgs/newimage.png");
      alert($(".dragme").attr('src'));
    }
});
```

2nd Solution

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QsjqP/124/)**

```
$(".dragme").draggable();

$(".dropzone1").droppable({
    accept:".dragme",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      $(ui.draggable).attr("src", "../imgs/newimage.png");

    }
});
```

From the [drop event documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop):

```
This event is triggered when an accepted draggable is dropped 'over' (within the 
tolerance of) this droppable. In the callback, $(this) represents the droppable 
the draggable is dropped on. ui.draggable represents the draggable.
```

Comment: unfortunately still nothing, I even put the alert in there after your ui.item.attr line and that didn't activate either.

Comment: jsfiddle added to the question

Comment: thank you, they work as much as one box moves and is dropped into the other, however I would like the box which is draggable to change once it has been dropped. http://jsfiddle.net/QsjqP/127/ you can see in there that although the src attribute should change, it doesn't.
@sangram