# Can you work out why my .js file doesn't seem to be linking to my html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWDtR/) of my site (very premature), seems to work fine on there, but I'm not getting any results at all locally, either in the preview window in Komodo or when I open it in Safari.

Here are my links to the js file, JQuery and JQuery UI I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"</script>
```

I know the links all work because they all link directly to the file or website when I click on it in Komodo.

What's going wrong for me? I've made other working sites but this one just isn't going well for me.

Help?

Also, if anyone could shed any light on this JQuery question I would be eternally great full :
[Attempting to use JQuery to change an img src of draggable object when dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124204/attempting-to-use-jquery-to-change-an-img-src-of-draggable-object-when-dropped)

Comment: Try moving `"js/scripts.js"` so it's after the other 2.

Comment: That worked thanks! Aaah can't believe it was that! never had that issue before

Comment: you probably use jquery stuff in your scripts.js then, you need to include functions you are going to use firts, then the file that uses them. Think of it as including jquery at the bottom of the page, it would be the same

Answer (score 4):

put a '`>`' in front of all the '`</script>`'

Comment: ah my bad, didn't copy it onto here properly, but still no hope, thanks though

Comment: @JoShlong23 Please update the code in your question to reflect the actual code that causes the error. Additionally, please provide details about the result rather than the non-specific "_but still no hope._"

Comment: My problem was that the animation I had written in my scripts.js wasn't happening, I suspected the issue was my links to that file and Jonathan has helped me fix the issue by putting my script after the JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Your script tags are missing the closing `>` on the `<script>` tags. You have essentially `<script </script>`.

Also, as Jonathan mentioned in the comment, you likely want to your own scripts *after* jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

replace your code with following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

you didn't close the bracket